# Intersection point between 2 lines drawn incorrectly

Tags: graphics, geometry

I would like to know why the intersection of the 2 lines computed with FindInstance is not drawn at the intersection of the 2 lines. Thank you.

```
point1 = {57.7538, 44.0056};
point2 = {57.7607, 43.9983};
line1 = Line[{point1, point2}];
line2 = Line[{{54.3101, 40.715}, {58.4058, 44.624}}];
intersectionPoint = 
  First[{x, y} /. 
    FindInstance[{x, y} ∈ line1 && {x, y} ∈ 
       line2, {x, y}]];
Graphics[{{Gray, line1}, {PointSize[Large], 
   Point[{point1, point2}]}, {PointSize[Large], Red, 
   Point[intersectionPoint]}}, Prolog -> {Thick, Dashed, line2}]
```

[image: Graphics of the intersection point]

Comment: Provided code works fine for me. Have you tried restarting your kernel?

Comment: Works for me, too.

Comment: @m_goldberg I see the point not on the intersection like the OP, on v11.0.1 x64 with windows 10. It is quite weird because if you remove the `Dashed` it shows correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer, but another comment that requires graphics.

I am running V11.0.1 on OS X 10.10.2 (Yosemite) and this is what I see.

```
Graphics[
  {{Gray, line1},
   {PointSize[Large], Point[{point1, point2}]}, 
   {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[intersectionPoint]}}, 
  Prolog -> {Thick, Dashed, line2}]
```

[image: plot1]

The `Prolog` option is only needed because `line2` is much longer than `line1` and would totally dominate the plot. Putting it in a prolog means `line2`'s end points are ignored for setting the plot range (it gets clipped). The option can be eliminated by scaling `line2` about the intersection.

```
Graphics[
  {{Gray, line1},
   {Thick, Dashed, Scale[line2, .002, intersectionPoint]},
   {PointSize[Large], Point[{point1, point2}]},
   {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[intersectionPoint]}}]
```

[image: plot2]

In both case, the intersection is drawn correctly. I can only conclude the problem is OS dependent.

Comment: Scaling line2 about the intersection works. Thank you for your help. Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

More an observation than an answer (I post it here because I cannot put figures in comments).
The behaviour seems to be caused by the `Dashed` attribute, and it is the line, not the point, that is not drawn correctly.

Op's code for me (v11.0.1 x64 on Windows 10) produces

```
point1 = {57.7538, 44.0056};
point2 = {57.7607, 43.9983};
line1 = Line[{point1, point2}];
line2 = Line[{{54.3101, 40.715}, {58.4058, 44.624}}];
intersectionPoint =
  First[{x, y} /.
    FindInstance[{x, y} ∈ line1 && {x, y} ∈
       line2, {x, y}]];
Graphics[{
  {Gray, line1},
  {PointSize[Large], Point[{point1, point2}]},
  {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[intersectionPoint]}
  },
 Prolog -> {Dashed, line2},
 Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Large
 ]
```

[image]

Removing the `Dashed` attribute in the `Prolog` option, I get:

```
point1 = {57.7538, 44.0056};
point2 = {57.7607, 43.9983};
line1 = Line[{point1, point2}];
line2 = Line[{{54.3101, 40.715}, {58.4058, 44.624}}];
intersectionPoint =
  First[{x, y} /.
    FindInstance[{x, y} ∈ line1 && {x, y} ∈
       line2, {x, y}]];
Graphics[{
  {Gray, line1},
  {PointSize[Large], Point[{point1, point2}]},
  {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[intersectionPoint]}
  },
 Prolog -> {line2},
 Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Large
 ]
```

[image]

Drawing `line2` inside the same `Graphics` as the rest of the objects doesn't change this, so it doesn't look like a problem in `Prolog`.

Even better, the lower the `Dashing`, the further away the line is drawn from the intersection point:

```
point1 = {57.7538, 44.0056};
point2 = {57.7607, 43.9983};
line1 = Line[{point1, point2}];
line2 = Line[{{54.3101, 40.715}, {58.4058, 44.624}}];
intersectionPoint =
  First[{x, y} /.
    FindInstance[{x, y} ∈ line1 && {x, y} ∈
       line2, {x, y}]];
Graphics[{
  {Gray, line1},
  {PointSize[Large], Point[{point1, point2}]},
  {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[intersectionPoint]}
  },
 Prolog -> Map[{Hue[10 #], Dashing@#, line2} &]@Range[0, .5, 0.01],
 Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Large
 ]
```

[image]

I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. Kind regards